# Prove the invertible $2\times 2$ matrices with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ form a group

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be the set of all $2\times2$ matrices $ \left( {\begin{array}{cc}
   a & b \\
   c & d \\
  \end{array} } \right) $ where
$a, b, c, d$ are integers modulo $p$, $p$ a prime number, such that $ad - bc \neq 0$. We define the binary operation as the normal $2\times 2$ matrix multiplication. Prove that $G$ is a group.

Now, I have seen numerous threads regarding this topic in the website citing the same question and each and every one of them has all the answers explained in terms of fields,rings,etc. However, I do want an answer using the elementary approach. I have already proven the closure property, associative property and identity property . However, I am not being able to prove the inverse property . How to prove that for every  element  $A\in G$ , $\exists A^{-1}\in G$ such that $A.A^{-1}=A^{-1}.A=I$ . Now, $A^{-1}$ do exist for every $A\in G $ but , how to prove that $A^{-1}\in G $ ? I am not quite getting it...

Comment: I have seen numerous threads regarding this topic in the website citing the same question and each and every one of them has all the answers explained in terms of fields,rings,etc. However, I do want an answer using the elementary approach.

Comment: Do you know a general formula for the inverse of a $2\times 2$ matrix? This will give what you want.

Comment: $A^{-1} = adj(A) / det(A)$.

Comment: The title of this post is not very good! Titles are supposed to describe briefly what the question is about.

Comment: @Marcos Yeah! It's what David Lui wrote ...but how to prove that $A^{-1}\in G$ as $A^{-1}=\frac{1}{(ad-bc)^2}$$\times$ $ \left( {\begin{array}{cc}
   a & b \\
   c & d \\
  \end{array} } \right) $ but then again $a,b,c,d\in\{0,1,2,3,...,p-1\}$ but $a/(ad-bc)$ and so on may not be in the set of integers modulo $p$...

Comment: @DerekHolt Actually that was supposed to be my original question about which I want to know about a part of the solution ...so I posted it ....Thank you!

Comment: That's not quite right - the formula is $A^{-1}=\dfrac1{ad-bc}\begin{pmatrix}d&-c\\-b&a\end{pmatrix}$. You can check this by multiplying by $A$. Now what do you know about inverses modulo a prime?

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger Yeah! U r right...must have been a typo ...however, can u please explain what is meant by "inverses modulo a prime" ...I know about  $a \mod p$  such that $a\in{0,1,2,3,...,p-1}$ ...but what are "inverses modulo a prime" and whose inverse are u talking about?....I am not getting it....

Comment: @Franklin For what $a$ can you find $b$ such that $ab\equiv1\pmod p$?

Comment: Do you know that the nonzero integers modulo $p$ form a group under multiplication modulo $p$?

Comment: @Auturo Magidin Well, u see that I have just started group theory and I don't know about rings,fields,etc...Also the statement that "the non-zero integers modulo $p$ form a group under multiplication modulo $p$" may be true but still, I am having trouble proving the jnverse property ...can I always find a $b$ such that $ab\equiv 1 (\mod p )$?...

Comment: I did not talk or mention rings or fields. I asked about one specific group, and since the problem is about proving something is a group, you must know what a group is. If you are not familiar with the fact about integers modulo $p$, then you should not be doing this problem. This problem clearly presupposes knowledge about the arithmetical properties of the integers modulo $p$ so the question is really why are you attempting this problem before learning the necessary basics? Also, I don't get notified of your comment if you misspell my name.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I do know that u didn't mention rings or fields in the comment but u did edit the title of my post and added a symbol $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ which I believe ,I will get to know when I study rings, fields,etc.Now,I know what is integers modulo $p$ is,however , as I have clearly mentioned in my previous post that I am not getting how to prove the inverse propertyi.e can I always find $b\in G$ such that $ab\equiv 1(\mod p)$? This is the question I asked in the comment(about which u r talking about)...and sorry if I mispelled ur name...that was clearly unintentional...Thank you!

Comment: That symbol means "the integers modulo $p$". Use \pmod{p} to get the space and parentheses mod notation, not whatever you are using. Like I said: the property you are asking about is a basic property about modular arithmetic, that you are clearly expected to know **before** you even attempt the problem in the post. Which means you should not be attempting the problem in your post, and you should not be asking about prerequisites in comments. You should be learning the basics instead. Comments are not the place for you to learn basic modular arithmetic.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Sorry! But I can't agree with you at all...I was following a book called  Topics in Algebra by I.N Herstein ...it was given in a group theory chapter ...before that they had a preliminary chapter stating sets, basic mapping and basic number theory  and in the next chapter they had this problem as an exercise to the reader...so I don't think that the property ur talking about is the only approach towards solving the problem...and it's true...I don't know the property but it's not a perquisite else it would not have been presented in the book....

Comment: I am familiar with that book, and what I've mentioned *is* basic number theory. You need to review that chapter again. And given that I know how to solve the problem and you do not, do you really think you are in a position to disagree with me about what you need in order to solve the problem? One would think that your lack of knowledge would preclude you from deciding that I must be wrong and you, in your admitted lack of knowledge, must be right about what you need to know or do not need to know. Go learn basic number theory, because that is what you need to know and do not.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I don't know whether ur familiar with the book or not but I do know that ur over exaggerating things...anyways I got my answer...Thank you!...

Comment: I am so familiar that it is the book I learned abstract algebra from. But thank you for insinuating that I am either lying, exaggerating, or don't know what I am talking about... all from a position of acknowledged ignorance on your part.

Comment: @Aturo Magidin so u can reply to all comments and make chats unnecessarily long and drift so much away from the topic ....but u cannot answer a query in the comment section (although that's nowhere given on mathstack exchange guidelines ) but u have no problem in doing extended unnecessary discussions (which is a part of math stack exchange guidelines)...how funny, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Euclid's algorithm (Bezout's Identity) Holds for PID rings, if the greatest common divisor between $a$ and $b$ is $d$ then there exists $x,y$ such that $ax+by=d$. Thus for any prime $p$ and relatively prime integer $a$ we have $gcd(a,p)=1$ by the above there exists $x,y$ such that $ax+py=1$ take module $p$ gives up $ax\cong 1 \mod p$ which means that $x$ is the multiplicative inverse of $a$ in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$

Check: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity

Comment: so that means since we have $ax\equiv 1(mod p) $ so, even if $x\notin G $ , we have $x\equiv q(mod p)$ such that $q\in G $ . Thus, $ax\equiv aq\equiv 1 (mod p)$ and hence $aq\equiv 1 (mod p)$ where $q\in G$. So, we do have an inverse ,right?...

Comment: what do you men by $x\notin G$? any integer is in an class mod p. I mean $14 \cong 4 \mod 5$ but still you can represent the class by 14

Comment: I get the idea...but here, the main idea is that the elements of $G$ is $\{0,1,2,...,p-1\}$. I know that  we can represent the class by any suitable integer but, when we talk about integers modulo $p$ , it was given in the book , we consider the above set ...and the main idea of this problem was to show that the inverse matrix has all the elements from that set (,I mentioned).....Thanks a lot!...